# Google Maps javascript Api Don't work on localhost

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, geolocation

Hi I enable JavaScript API in my Google Console, but It's not working for PHP server in http://localhost , It only works when I open it Directly in the browser as HTML page, I am using the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Place Autocomplete Address Form</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">
    <style>
      #locationField, #controls {
        position: relative;
        width: 480px;
      }
      #autocomplete {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 99%;
      }
      .label {
        text-align: right;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 100px;
        color: #303030;
      }
      #address {
        border: 1px solid #000090;
        background-color: #f0f0ff;
        width: 480px;
        padding-right: 2px;
      }
      #address td {
        font-size: 10pt;
      }
      .field {
        width: 99%;
      }
      .slimField {
        width: 80px;
      }
      .wideField {
        width: 200px;
      }
      #locationField {
        height: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 2px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="locationField">
      <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address"
             onFocus="geolocate()" type="text"></input>
    </div>

    <table id="address">
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Street address</td>
        <td class="slimField"><input class="field" id="street_number"
              disabled="true"></input></td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="2"><input class="field" id="route"
              disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">City</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" id="locality"
              disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">State</td>
        <td class="slimField"><input class="field"
              id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true"></input></td>
        <td class="label">Zip code</td>
        <td class="wideField"><input class="field" id="postal_code"
              disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Country</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field"
              id="country" disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <script>
// This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
// of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

var placeSearch, autocomplete;
var componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};

function initAutocomplete() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
  // location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
      {types: ['geocode']});

  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
  // fields in the form.
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}

// [START region_fillform]
function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }

  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
}
// [END region_fillform]

// [START region_geolocation]
// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: geolocation,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy
      });
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}
// [END region_geolocation]

    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
        async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For cases like this, when a 3rd party script require a live server to correctly work and you have to test from localhost, try to use some tunneling service.

They are a services that offers to you a public url routed to your localhost.
All of this is usually achieved by installing a vendor software on your machine.

I've only used ngrok from windows., from this link -> [ngrok.com](https://ngrok.com/)

It's simple, it doesn't need any installation, only download and run a simple command from your shell and you'll have a public url, known only by you and yuo can test your website as it is already online.

Example:

- download ngrok in a folder
- open windows cmd in that folder
- launch the command ngrok.exe http localhost:[YOUR_PORT]

Technique like this are also usefull for testing paypal ipn, facebook app, etc etc

But give a try also to other vendor that fits your needs.

Bye

Comment: Cool I tested and it works, it do not solve the problem with php server but it's a alternative, thanks for your answer

Comment: Another question  ngrok it's installed as enviroment variable? or do I need to configure it?

Comment: Please check now, however you have just to download the software and run the command from shell as i've added to the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
        async defer></script>
```

this script to add your google API_KEY

Comment: I already did but I did't posted the api here because of public code, it's a problem with the api that require a live server to work correctly. any way thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

open console and refresh your code to check api error.
google api not a free also billing account required.