# Google maps places library not working on Asp.Net localhost

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'm using Google Maps Javascript API with drawing and places library in Asp.Net MVC application. Drawing library is working fine but places library is not working on localhost.

I'm following [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox) example from official documentation, if example code is saved as simple *.html file then it works fine as shown below:

[image: Google Maps Places JavaScript library loaded from file system]

However if I copy same code in MVC or WebForms application and open page using localhost (IISExpress) then it stops working unexpectedly, as shown below:

[image: Google Maps Places JavaScript library failed to load from localhost]

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43192182/google-maps-javascript-api-dont-work-on-localhost) I have tried tunneling to expose port 80 and other as well but all in vain. I'm stuck here probably i'm missing anything, any guidance will be highly appreciated.

**UPDATE: Console Errors**

[image: Console errors]

All APIs calls are returned with status 200 in network tab although there are errors in console but those are related to billing info requirement.

Comment: Look in your developer console and post the errors you are seeing especially in the network tab

Comment: I have the same problem in a http:// page. Try to test your code in an https:// page - for example Codepen to see if it works.

Comment: @MattiPrice I have updated the question with console errors screenshot.

Comment: @enxaneta I have tried to test using https by enabling SSL in project properties but got no luck.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of after you start typing into the search bar?

Comment: Have you enabled billing with a credit card on the account for that key?

Comment: @MattiPrice screenshots are already added in the post.

Comment: @geocodezip In same project I'm using Drawing library without billing information and it's working fine. When billing information is missing Google adds a watermark of "For Development purpose only".

Comment: Perhaps the places library (which requires interaction with Google's servers, unlike the `DrawingManager`) is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the Google map now you must create a billing account before applying the key. All Google Maps Platform API requests must include an API key;

- Google Maps no longer support key-less access.
- You must enable billing on each of your projects.

See [Guide for Existing Users](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/user-guide/?__utma=102347093.1599021834.1533701670.1536125401.1536125401.1&__utmb=102347093.0.10.1536125401&__utmc=102347093&__utmx=-&__utmz=102347093.1536125401.1.1.utmcsr=google%7Cutmccn=(organic)%7Cutmcmd=organic%7Cutmctr=(not%20provided)&__utmv=-&__utmk=187286952&_ga=2.67529105.1602093702.1535945502-1599021834.1533701670) for more information.

Comment: For development purpose I'm using Drawing library without billing information and it's working fine. When billing information is missing Google adds a watermark of "For Development purpose only".

Comment: Please create billing account for development activities and It will enable all the libraries. Google map gives you 200 credits for free.

Answer (score 0):

Create Billing account then make sure that you API key is correct